# UpdateProgress spinner disappears after 90 seconds

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

My UpdateProgress is out side the UpdatePanel, I have tried the below things

1. Added the JavaScript, added the "AsyncPostBackTimeout=3600" in Master Page
2. Added the below code in `Page-Load` event

   `ScriptManager _scriptMan = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);`
   `_scriptMan.AsyncPostBackTimeout = 3600;`
3. added the below changes in web.config file:

   `<system.web>`
   `<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" requestLengthDiskThreshold="1000" executionTimeout="3600" />`
   `</system.web>`

After this changes also, UpdateProgress spinner appears for 90 seconds.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem until I set the AsyncPostBackTimeout on the ScriptManager tag itself.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"
 AsyncPostBackTimeout="600" />
```